# Android's Repo not syncing branches other than master

Tags: git, repo

I'm using [Repo](https://source.android.com/source/using-repo.html) for a multi-repository dev-environment.
When trying to update all repos, I do a `repo sync` and the output shows something like:

```
...
From github.com:<repo-name>
   1c9accf..4b2f449  feature/branch1 -> origin/feature/branch1
...
```

`feature/branch1` is the branch I'm currently working on and which is a couple of commits behind `origin/feature/branch1`. It is tracking the remote branch.

But after the `repo sync` the local branch is still not updated. 
Repositories that are still on `master` are working fine - they output the following:

```
...
Fetching projects:  77% (7/9)  From github.com:<repo-name-on-master>
   eb99bff..372e69f  master     -> origin/master
Fetching projects: 100% (9/9), done.

<project-name>/: manifest switched refs/heads/master...master
project <project-name>/
Updating eb99bff..372e69f
Fast-forward
 README.md | 2 +-
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+), 1 deletion(-)
...
```

So the last part - the updating - is not happening for the `branch1`. Why is that?

`default.xml` looks like this and is in a separate repo on github:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<manifest>
  <remote name="origin" fetch=".." />
  <default revision="master" remote="origin" sync-j="4" />

  <project name="repo-name" path="api" />
  <project name="repo-name-2" path="docs" />
</manifest>
```

`.git/config` looks like this:

```
[core]
    repositoryformatversion = 0
    filemode = true
    ignorecase = true
    precomposeunicode = true
[filter "lfs"]
    smudge = git-lfs smudge --skip -- %f
[remote "origin"]
    url = git@github.com:<repo-name>
    projectname = <project-name>
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
[branch "master"]
    remote = origin
    merge = refs/heads/master
[branch "feature/branch1"]
    remote = origin
    merge = refs/heads/feature/branch1
```

Comment: What do you mean by "But after the repo sync the local branch is still not updated."? What happens when you checkout the local branch?

Comment: It's already checked out but the newer commits weren't fetched or pulled

Comment: Are you sure that the commits were not fetched? I suggest you learn about the difference between fetch and pull. You might just need to merge with the remote tracking branch.

Comment: I know the difference between pull and fetch - that's why I said they were neither fetched nor pulled (fetched + merged).

Comment: Does `git log origin/feature/branch1` show? Does it have the new commits?

Answer (score 1):

> If the project has already been synchronized once, then repo sync is equivalent to:
>
> git remote update
>
> git rebase origin/< BRANCH >
>
> where < BRANCH > is the currently checked-out branch in the local project directory. If the local branch is not tracking a branch in the remote repository, then no synchronization will occur for the project.

The commits from the remote feature branch are there (unless the remote tracking branch not configured correctly). They are just not at the tip of your local branch.

Comment: I put some more info in the question - I'm just not getting why `master` is working and `branch1` not

Comment: yes, but why isn't repo doing that? when I do this manually (`git remote update` and `git rebase origin/branch1`) everything is up-to-date, just like you would expect it to be. but not when doing `repo sync`.

Answer (score 1):

`repo sync` only update the branch you specified in manifest files, as shown in your question,  it is `revision="master"`.

If you want to sync branch1, you need modify your manifest file.

[Repo command reference](https://source.android.com/source/using-repo.html) gives some details about `repo sync`

Comment: hmmm, that's what I thought. But kind of expecting/hoping for something more like: if you start a branch with `repo start feature/test1 .` that `repo` would then know about the branch and also update it on `sync`:(

Comment: @pkyeck, I have the same expecting with you, but according to document of repo, It is recommended to use `local_manifests` to replace the original project with your own one.